# Trying to create an installer to make a XNA game playable on other computers

Tags: c#, xna, installation

I am a student in computer engineering and for our first year project we had to create a XNA game. And I really liked it, so I decided to create my own RPG Horror Game.

Since I want to make it as good as possible, I tried to share it with friends so that they would test it but they couldn't install it without having to install XNA Framework, and to do so something else like Visual C# Express for example.
I've looked through topics and there doesn't seem to be any other way to avoid that, I at least wanted to create an Installer so they wouldn't have to download anything themselves (they are not really into computer sciences so it may be difficult for some). So I [downloaded Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/download.html) and tried to do so, but it still doesn't work as planned...

So my question is: Has somebody has done this before, or does anybody knows a way to create a good installer  I want to release it as a demo for the moment so it would be a lot easier for me...

Edit: 
BradleyDotNet: my bad, I will be more careful next time
Elias: Yes, that what I tried the first time. The publish option gives me a File folder, a setup.exe and a .application
I tried to run them on a computer that didn't have XNA and it still wants me to install it before, and so to install Windows Phone, Visual C# or something like this :/ I think I followed the tutorial and maybe I did something wrong, But since that's not the first time I try this option it bothers me.

Thanks a lot for your help

Stan

Comment: Even though you are writing an RPG, this doesn't have to do with the RPG tag (and doesn't impact the question anyways!).

Comment: I think [One Click Deployment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/bb464156.aspx#click_once) is what you are looking for. Edit: it says on the page I linked you "The ClickOnce feature for XNA Game Studio automatically includes all of the required software packages as part of the installation package"

Comment: You may want to check your reference properties. Highlight each library included in your project that is part of the xna framework and open the properties window. Set the copy local property to true. That's how I got around the install issue.

Comment: Okay, so Elias was right. I had indeed used ClickOnce correctly but one of the needed component was unticked, and that was the problem. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Xbox Live community forums](http://xboxforums.create.msdn.com/forums/t/1989.aspx):

> There are several tools available that can be used to create
>   installers.  Here are some options:
>
> 1. WiX - [creating
>      an MSI for an XNA Framework game](http://blogs.msdn.com/astebner/archive/2008/11/17/9115792.aspx)
> 2. Inno Setup - http://forums.xna.com/thread/2828.aspx
>      or http://www.gamedev.net/community/forums/topic.asp?topic_id=498463
> 3. XNAInstaller - http://www.codeplex.com/xnainstaller
>      or http://www.nuclex.org/installer
> 4. [Using
>      the Visual Studio bootstrapper to install XNA Framework game
>      dependencies](http://blogs.msdn.com/astebner/archive/2008/11/21/9132456.aspx)
> 5. [NSIS (Nullsoft Scriptable Install System)](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/)

You can also try the ClickOnce functionality provided by the framework, make sure all the necessary items are selected (I think you already tried that).